# Optimal substructure and dynamic programming for a variant of the rod cutting problem

Tags: algorithms, optimization, dynamic-programming, recurrence-relation

The rod-cutting problem described in [Section 15.1 of CLRS, 3rd edition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms) is the following.

> Given a rod of length $n$ inches and a table of prices $p_i$ for $i = 1, 2, \ldots, n$, determine the maximum revenue $r_n$ obtainable by cutting up the rod and selling the pieces.

This can be solved by dynamic programming with the recursion (consider the leftmost piece of length $j$):
$$R(i) = \max_{1 \le j \le i} \Big(p_j + R(i-j)\Big),\; R(0) = 0,$$
where $R(i)$ denotes the maximum revenue obtainable by cutting up a rod of length $i$.

In exercise $15.3$-$5$, a variant is considered:

> we also have limit $l_i$ on the number of pieces of length $i$ that we are allowed to produce, for $i = 1, 2, \ldots, n$.

***Problem:*** Is this variant of the rod cutting problem solvable using dynamic programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Answer My Own Question:***

Let $L$ be the length limit array.

Define $R(i, L)$ to be the maximum revenue obtainable by cutting up a rod of length $i$ with the length limit array $L$. The recursion is (consider the leftmost piece of length $j$; the base cases are not included):

$$R(i, L) = \max_{1 \le j \le i \land L_j \ge 1} \Big(p_j + R\big(i-j, L[j \mapsto L_j-1]\big)\Big),$$
where $L[j \mapsto L_j - 1]$ leaves other length limit than $L_j$ unchanged.

Comment: Another, maybe more elegant way would be to add base cases $R(i, L) = -\infty$ if $\exists j. L[j] < 0$. (For expressing the recurrence; an implementation would proceed as you propose.)

Comment: FWIW, the search space is huge compared to the original problem; the resulting algorithm is pseudo-polynomial at best. I wonder if there's not better way to look at the problem. Hm.